# Csc.exe compiles "different" .dlls from same .cs

Tags: c#, msbuild, diff, csc, binary-reproducibility

Give a source .cs file as simple as below, is there any way to produce identical .dlls with MSBuild (or at least with csc.exe), so their binary hash would match?

**foo.cs**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar;
}
```

**foo.bat**

```
del foo*.dll

csc /t:library foo.cs
move foo.dll foo1.dll

csc /t:library foo.cs
move foo.dll foo2.dll

powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem foo*.dll | ForEach-Object { $_.CreationTime = $_.LastWriteTime = $_.LastAccessTime = \"2013-03-15\" }"
```

Sample binary diff report is at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/65419748/CscBin.html

Does anyone know what those differences are and how to get around them?

Comment: Yeah @JonSkeet - there's no way that I'm aware of to generate identical compiled output between subsequent compilations - it's geared to *always* generate unique output, otherwise you'd never know you recompiled it.

Comment: Thanks. So given binary hash is not an option and creation/lastmodified stamps are unreliable, how would one compare project artefacts in general and dlls specifically without access to source control history?

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov: I generally wouldn't try to. This is presumably part of some bigger requirement - so post that bigger requirement as a new question, understanding that comparing the binaries isn't a good solution.